# Awakening iOS app from paired Apple Watch

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchconnectivity

Documentation states that when Watch app sends `WCSession.default.sendMessage` to the paired iOS app, iOS app wakes up in background:

> Calling this method from your WatchKit extension while it is active
> and running wakes up the corresponding iOS app in the background and
> makes it reachable.

My question: will it really wake up even if was killed by user (by swiping it out)?

And will `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` be called as a part of awakening process?

I am asking to make sure that it's sufficient to only call `WCSession.default.activate()` and set delegate in `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`.